# ember pick-a-date how to pull value?

Tags: ember.js, pickadate

There is a pick-a-date add-on for Ember found [here](https://github.com/AddJam/ember-cli-pickadate).

```
{{pick-a-date date=(readonly date) on-selected=(action (mut date)) placeholder="Pick a date" options=(readonly extraPickadateOptions)}}
```

How would I pass a saved date value to the tag?  The below (value=date) does not seem to work?

```
{{pick-a-date value=date date=(readonly date) on-selected=(action (mut date)) placeholder="Pick a date" options=(readonly extraPickadateOptions)}}
```

Or what if I wanted to change the value from 'date' to something different... for example dob... so it would 'mimic' this

```
{{input value=dob}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried using this addon and faced same issue. I need date in timestamp format and I implemented like following. You can check this,

```
{{pikaday-input  
    value=inputDateValue       
    onSelection=(action 'setSelectedDate') }}
```

For getting the value and binding that to object, I added following code in action handler,

```
actions : {
    setSelectedDate : function (date) {
        //To get the timestamp in seconds
        let timestamp = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);
        this.set("inputDateValue", date);
        // Used timestamp for setting value to object
        record.set("dateTime", timestamp);
    }
}
```

For setting the value I used folowing code,

```
if(record.get("dateTime") {
    let date = record.get("dateTime") * 1000;
    let dateValue = new Date(date);
    this.set("inputDateValue", dateValue);
}
```